# Generators of $H^1_{dR}(S^1)$ and angular forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

I am trying to understand and "visualize" the generator of the first de Rham cohomology group of the circle and the intuition behind the concept of angular form.

$H^1(S^1)$ can be computed from Mayer-Vietoris sequence obtaining $\dim H^1(S^1)= 1$ and from the coboundary map we obtain a generator $\omega_{MV}$ of $H^1(S^1)$ as a bump form with support (in a connected component of) the intersection of the two open sets used in M-V, that is, a bump form on the circle (say with integral equal to 1). Thus $H^1(S^1) = \langle [\omega_{MV}] \rangle$.

This form is sometimes called "angular form" but intuitively does not look like a "differential" of an angle (I know that the angle is a multifunction and hence we should use the universal cover of $S^1$ to properly discuss it, but we can get away with some careful intuition nonetheless).
Intuitively the angle "function" has a linear growth on the circle minus a point, thus I'd expect its "differential" to be a "constant" form.

Of course constant does not make sense for a 1-form. We can restate this by asking that this angular form should evaluate to a constant function when paired with the vector field $X = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ restricted to $S^1$. Of course such a form can be seen as the restriction of $xdy - ydx$ to $S^1$.

Without referring to the ambient space, we can construct a "constant" form $\omega_c$ gluing the forms $c\cdot dx$ on $U,V \simeq \mathbb{R}$ as follows.
Say $U \simeq_{\varphi_U} (0-\varepsilon,\pi +\varepsilon)$ and $V \simeq_{\varphi_V} (\pi-\varepsilon,2\pi +\varepsilon)$ just to fix the ideas. We have $$\varphi_U(U\cap V) = (0- \varepsilon,0+\varepsilon) \sqcup (\pi -\varepsilon,\pi+\varepsilon)$$
$$\varphi_V(U\cap V) = (2\pi- \varepsilon,2\pi +\varepsilon) \sqcup (\pi -\varepsilon,\pi+\varepsilon)$$
and the transition functions are the identity on the first compoment and the translation $\pm 2\pi$ on the second component, thus their jacobian is always the identity. Moreover on $\mathbb{R}$ the forms $dx$ are translation invariant, i.e. $dx_p = dx_{p+q}$, thus in the end $\varphi_{UV}^*dx = dx$.
This defines $\omega_c$ as $\omega_c|_U = c \cdot \varphi_U^*dx$ and $\omega_c|_V = c \cdot \varphi_U^*dx$.

These forms are closed by definition and they are intuitively exact since if there was a function on $S^1$ with a constant differential, it must be constantly increasing, but this is impossible on $S^1$. Thus $H^1(S^1) = \langle [\omega_{c}] \rangle$.

This form is what I would call **angular form**, of course, since $H^1$ is 1-dimensional, $[\omega_{c}] = [\omega_{MV}]$ thus by extension we call also $\omega_{MV}$ an angular form.

Since $S^1$ is compact, we also have $H_c^1(S^1) = \langle [\omega_{c}] \rangle = \langle [\omega_{MV}] \rangle$.

Does my reasoning make sense?

Thanks

EDIT: I've rewritten the construction of "constant" 1-forms to make it clearer. Seems to me it that the use of partition of unity it not even necessary.

Comment: How would you glue together the two "constant" forms? The transition function does not map "$dx$ in $U$" to "$dx$ in $V$". The classical "angular form" can be seen as the push-forward of $dt$ by the map $\phi \colon \Bbb R \to S^1$ given by $\phi(t) = e^{it}$, hence its name

Comment: @Didier 1) What do you mean by pushforward of a differential form? Maybe since the map is a local diffeomorphism we can pullback locally using local inverses and glue them back together? 2) I don't see why the gluing that I proposed should not produce a well defined 1-form. Of course the orientation of $\mathbb{R}$ should be chosen in a compatible way

Comment: 1) It is defined as $(\phi_* dt)_p(v) = dt_{q}(d\phi_q^{-1}(v))$ for any $q$ with $\phi(q) = p$ (luckily it does not depend on $q$) 2) How do you identify the two forms on the separate components? Please write down your construction. In general, $U$ and $V$ are identified by the inverse map $x \mapsto 1/x$ on $U\cap V \simeq \Bbb R^*$, and "$dx$" on the left is equal to "$-\frac{1}{x^2}dx$" on the right

Comment: 1) But this requires some assumptions on $\phi$, for example the existence of a local inverse 2) I have rewritten the construction of such forms trying to make it clearer

Comment: Ok, so your construction is more that of the circle as the quotient $\Bbb R / 2\pi \Bbb Z$, and in that case it agrees with the one I gave above. I though you were gluing the $dx$'s of the two charts of the stereographical atlas, which in that case would not have made sense

Comment: Remember that two $1$-forms on the circle are cohomologous (i.e., represent the same cohomology class) if and only if they have the same integral over the circle. So something "bump function"-ish is cohomologous to some multiple of $d\theta$.